# Jquery UI date picker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use jquery ui to add date picker when i click on a text field. But it's Year and month selector are not working. What is the mistake?

```
function date() {

                                        $("#dob").datepicker();
                                        $("#dob").datepicker("show");
                                        $("#dob").datepicker({
                                            changeMonth: true,
                                            changeYear: true,
                                            yearRange: "1900:1996"
                                        });


                                    }
```

And my input field code is this

```
<input type="text" onclick="date()" id="dob"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not to call a function on click of input and bind datepicker every time. Also just one call is enough rather calling it three times.

first call is binding datepicker with default setting

```
$("#dob").datepicker();
```

second call is to show datepicker, it is not required as on click of input it will popup automatically

```
$("#dob").datepicker("show");
```

and third call is to show datepicker with your options like show year and month

```
$("#dob").datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   yearRange: "1900:1996"
});
```

And you need only third datepicker call for your requirement,
Use below code

```
<input type="text" id="dob"/>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#dob").datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       yearRange: "1900:1996"
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmrdb33s/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using the following code

```
     <form>
        <fieldset> 
        <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>  
        </fieldset>
     </form>
```

The script as follows

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1900:1996"

    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvkganesh/p9fr9tc2/)